# Definition of right cancellation in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to define in a Isabelle theory  the property of right cancellation  for function composition but
there are some errors that I can't to fix.

The definition I would like specify in Isabelle is the following:

> f : A → B has the property of right cancellation iff
>   ∀ C : (∀ g, h : B → C ) : g ◦ f = h ◦ f =⇒ g = h

Is it possible? Or more precisely, is it possible to quantify over a type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to explicitly quantify over types. If you prove a lemma with a type variable, it is implicitly proved for all instantiations of the type.

In some cases you can use a workaround and use the type `V` from the AFP entry [ZFC_in_HOL](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/ZFC_in_HOL.html). This type `V` basically is a type with so many elements that there is an injective function from (almost?) every HOL type into `V`. So in some cases it can be used as a kind of dynamic type to escape the type system.

```
theory ...
  imports "ZFC_in_HOL.ZFC_Typeclasses"
begin


definition right_cancellation :: "('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ bool"  where
  "right_cancellation f ≡ (∀g h :: 'b ⇒ V. g ∘ f = h ∘ f ⟶ g = h)"
```

In this case it is also possible to show that the definition is independent of the type used, so you might just use `bool`:

```
definition right_cancellation :: "'c itself ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ bool"  where
  "right_cancellation t f ≡ (∀ g h :: 'b ⇒ 'c. g ∘ f = h ∘ f ⟶ g = h)"

lemma 
  fixes f:: "'x ⇒ 'y"
  assumes as: "a1 ≠ (a2::'a)"
    and r: "right_cancellation (A::'a itself) f"
  shows "right_cancellation (B::'b itself) f"
```